# Datatable - After unbind() even sSearch is not taking search parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have written the following code for removing the ajax call after every keystroke.

`$(".dataTables_filter input")
            .unbind()
            .bind("input", function(e) {`

```
            if(this.value.length >= 99 || e.keyCode == 13) {
                oTable.api().search("loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val()).draw();
            }

            if(this.value == "") {
                oTable.api().search("loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val()).draw();
            }
            return;
        });
```

After this ajax call is not being fired after every keystroke but when it is being fired it is not sending the search parameter in the search box that is the sSearch parameter is blank.

According to my understanding `.unbind()` has unbinded the default behaviour. How do I bind the sSearch parameter again.

Comment: Has nothing to do with `unbind()`, `search()` searches within the table, it does not perform an ajax search. You just search in the table for whatever `"loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val()` produces.

Comment: @davidkonrad `$('#category').val` decides the column but the text entered in the search box is not coming in the sSearch parameter. And this is happening only after unbind(). How to get the value entered in the search box.

Comment: You are not adding `this.value` to the search, But again, I believe you are really off here, you cannot execute an ajax-search by inserting an url as search term.